Gauge invariant phase in projective representation of a group
I am reading a physics paper arXiv 1403.0575 on symmetry fractionalization in 2D topological order. It includes a brief description of the projective representation of a symmetry group $G$. For concreteness, $G$ is the space group of a lattice. In the following I will make some change of notations to focus on the math.
Let $g \in G$ be represented by an operator $U(g)$ on the Hilbert space (of a single anyon). In a projective representation (Eq. 1)
$$
U(g_1) U(g_2) = \omega(g_1,g_2) U(g_1 g_2),
$$
where $\omega: G \times G \to U(1)$ is a phase factor. Associativity in $G$ requires that $\omega$ satisfies the cocycle equation
$$
\omega(g_1,g_2) \omega(g_1 g_2,g_3)
= \omega(g_1,g_2 g_3) \omega(g_2 g_3).
$$
Since quantum states are defined up to a $U(1)$ phase factor, the operators $U(g)$ can be redefined by
$$
U'(g) = \lambda(g) U(g), \quad
\lambda: G \to U(1). 
$$
Under this "gauge transformation", $\omega$ is changed to (Eq. 6 in the reference got the numerator and denominator wrong)
$$
\omega'(g_1,g_2)
= \omega(g_1,g_2) 
\frac{\lambda(g_1) \lambda(g_2)}
{\lambda(g_1 g_2)}. 
$$
Suppose that some elements $g_1, ..., g_N \in G$ compose to the identity, i.e. $g_1 \cdots g_N = e$. The operators $U(g_1), ..., U(g_N)$ then satisfy
$$
U(g_1) \cdots U(g_N)
= \omega(g_1 \cdots g_N) U(e)
$$
where (Eq. 27)
$$
\omega(g_1 \cdots g_N)
= \omega(g_1,g_2) \omega(g_1 g_2,g_3)
\cdots \omega(g_1 \cdots g_{N-1},g_N)
$$
This can be obtained by evaluating $g_1 \cdots g_N$ in the order
$$
((((g_1 g_2) g_3) g_4) \cdots g_N)
$$
Here is my question:

The reference claims that this phase is invariant under the gauge transformation $U'(g) = \lambda(g) U(g)$, at least when $\omega(g_1,g_2)$ and $\lambda(g)$ are both restricted to take values in $\mathbb{Z}_2 = \{+1, -1\}$ (instead of the whole $U(1)$; this is the case in "$\mathbb{Z}_2$ topological order", which is the focus of the reference). But I cannot see why. My attempt is as follows.
$$
\begin{align*}
    \omega'(g_1 \cdots g_N)
    &= \omega(g_1,g_2)
    \frac{\lambda(g_1) \lambda(g_2)}
    {\lambda(g_1 g_2)}
    \omega(g_1g_2,g_3)
    \frac{\lambda(g_1 g_2) \lambda(g_3)}
    {\lambda(g_1 g_2 g_3)}
    \\ &\qquad \cdots
    \omega(g_1 \cdots g_{N-1},g_N)
    \frac{\lambda(g_1 \cdots g_2) \lambda(g_N)}
    {\lambda(g_1 \cdots g_N)}
    \\
    &= \omega(g_1 \cdots g_N)
    \frac{\lambda(g_1) \cdots \lambda(g_N)}
    {\lambda(g_1 \cdots g_N)}
\end{align*}
$$
Why $\lambda(g_1) \cdots \lambda(g_N) / \lambda(g_1 \cdots g_N) = 1$? How is this related to $g_1 \cdots g_N = e$?



Hi! Please ask only one question at a time.
